# Passing an int as the 4th argument in pthread_create in C

Tags: c, multithreading

```css
int threadreader(void* pos)
{
    int a, v;
    char *f;

    v = (long int) *pos;

    f = (char *)malloc(sizeof(SIZEFICHEIRO));
    a = randomnum(4);
    f = pickfile(a, f);
    return reader (v, f);
}


int main(){

    int i, pos, extra, retval,safe;
    pthread_t thread[K];

    for (i = 0; i < K; i++) 
    {
        pos = i * L/K * SIZECADEIA;
        safe = pthread_create( &thread[i], NULL, (void*) threadleitor, (void*) &pos);
        if (safe != 0)
        {
            perror ("Error creating threads");
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to pass the value of pos to the function threadreader because i'll need it then in function reader. The problem is that in the 4th argument of pthread_create it only works if I put the adress of pos (&pos). And in the end, when I try to access to the value of pos again it prints out the following errors:

```html
warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
     v = (long int) *pos;
                    ^
reader3.c:92:5: error: invalid use of void expression
     v = (long int) *pos;
```

Any idea of how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First cast the void pointer to an int pointer, and then dereference the value. Like this:

```
int threadreader(void* pos)
{
    int* p_pos = (int*) pos;
    int v = *p_pos;

    return v;
}
```

As commenters pointed out, you should make sure that the pointer points to a variable that is still "alive" when the thread is run.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem to fix compilation error, but the program logic is incorrect. When thread is running, pointer to local variable `pos` may be invalid. This is undefined behavior. Pass `pos` value to the thread instead of pointer:

```
int threadreader(void* pos)
{
    int v = (int) pos;
    ...
}

int pos;
...
pos = i * L/K * SIZECADEIA;
safe = pthread_create( &thread[i], NULL, (void*) threadreader, (void*) pos);
```

Generally, if you want to pass a pointer to thread, ensure that variable poined by this pointer exists and has an expected value.

BTW, thread function must return `void*` and not `int`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

Comment: He's passing `&pos` (not `pos`) which is fine as long as it's ensured the object doesn't become invalid. There are many other problems as well.

Comment: @BlueMoon: this code passes pointer to local variable `pos`' Variable may change. When program exits the loop, this pointer becomes invalid.